# Como saber que proyecto ejecuta a otro?

Tags: java, maven

Tengo un problema ya que tengo 3 programas A,B y C. En el cual A y B hacen uso de C. Esto atraves de maven (instalo el proyecto C )
Lo que pasa es que necesito condicionar una funcion para que el proyecto C distinga cuando es cuando el proyecto A lo llama y cuando es el B. No se si existe alguna libreria para saber desde que proyecto es llamado un metodo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta la página [ask]. Tu pregunta se orienta a obtener opiniones. De modo que posiblemente sea cerrada por no ajustarse al formato del sitio. Consulta **línea de comandos** casi todos los lenguajes tienen una manera de pasar parámetros al invocar programas (no creo que java sea la excepción).

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarle un parámetro y ya con eso tu envías "algo" (cadena o numero) que identifique a cada proyecto. El pase de parámetro de tu main(String[] args) te puede ser muy útil.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(args);
    }
```